# Kendo UI for Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I've started to work in an Angular Js application for the first time as a part of a project requirement. I'm getting many docs in the internet for installing Kendo for Angular but not for Angular Js. Can it be done for Angular Js through npm? If yes, how can it be done? It may sound like a silly question to some but would really appreciate if I get the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all you need about Kendo UI and npm [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/npm).

Basically, there are two packages: *Kendo UI Core*, which is the free non-commercial version and *Kendo UI Professional*, which is the commercial version.

The Kendo UI Core npm package name is `kendo-ui-core`.

Here's a link to the package page:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kendo-ui-core